# Set max width for Office UI Fabric TextField

Tags: office-ui-fabric

How do I set max width for a TextField? By default, the width is set to maximum size [image: Default TextField width]

Answer (score 3):

You can set the max-width property of the  component by implementing your own styles function as done in [this Codepen example](https://codepen.io/kevintcoughlin/pen/LJYzyM).

```
const getStyles = () => {
  return {
    root: {
      maxWidth: '100px'
    }
  }
};

<TextField 
  id='myTextField'
  spellcheck={ false }
  name='bar'          
  placeholder='Placeholder text' 
  defaultValue='Default text'
  styles={ getStyles }
/>
```

More documentation about this approach can be found at https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-react/wiki/Component-Styling#styles-prop.

Comment: Thank you. Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can add `style` attribute to a `<TextField>` component:

```
<TextField
   ...
   style={{maxWidth: '100px'}} 
/>
```

I hope it will help you.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use max-width to set the maximum width the container should have.

```css
.text-field{
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="text-field">
  <p>example<p> 
<div>
```